# Are all hive queries supported when hive is backed by hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I am primarily interested in GROUP BY, HAVING, AVG, PERCENTILE etc kind of aggregation functions.

If not, are there any alternatives to it?

Answer (score 1):

https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html is definitive list of UDF's and functions available in Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Those should all work. Hive table backed by HBase just uses a different storage handler as compared to a "regular" Hive table. However, as far as I know, a storage handler doesn't have any impact on what queries can be run through Hive.